# Read only part of file/ cut to specific symbol

Tags: r, bash

I have 100 files which all have a similar structure

```
line1
line2
stuff
RR
important stuff
```

The problem is that I want to cut when RR appears (which it does in each file). However, this is not always in the same line (it can be line 20, it can be line 35) but it is always there. Hence, is there any way in bash or R (when reading in the file) to that( just cuttign of the header)? I would prefer R.

Comment: why not read all and delete row where `RR` appears

Comment: sorry, you mean Rread in in R and delete manually? serious?

Comment: well not manually, but have script to do that for each file. By the way do you mean to delete rows with RR or anything after RR?

Comment: missunderstood the question as wanting to delete `RR`, so, I guess @Sven's answer is way to go

Answer (score 2):

You can read all rows and remove the unnecessary ones:

```
dat <- readLines(textConnection(
"line1
line2
stuff
RR
important stuff"))
# dat <- readLines("file.name")


dat[seq(which.max(dat == "RR") + 1, length(dat))]
# [1] "important stuff"
```

Comment: but wouldn't that mean that I had to copy past each file into the rep part of your answer? I might have misunderstood...

Comment: @user3069326 No, you can just use `dat <- readLines("file.name")`.

Comment: oh I think there is a misunderstanding , I wanted to get rid of Line1, line2 and stuff...while remaining all bits after RR....

Comment: @user3069326 OK, I understand. Have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Hey..somehow this only removes for me the line in which RR stands...however line1, line2,stuff and important stuff remain...

Comment: oh...I mean I used your code entirely...the readLines("kaa32.txt")

Comment: @user3069326 It seems that there is no line `"RR"` in the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `awk` available through `bash` you could do:

```
awk '(/RR/){p=1; next} (p){print}' < file.txt

$ cat file.txt
line1
line2
stuff
RR
important stuff
$ awk '(/RR/){p=1; next} (p){print}' < file.txt
important stuff
```

This sets a flag `p` when the 'RR' string is found, `next` causing the next line to be read without first evaluating `(p){ print }`. Subsequent lines will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few ways:

## Using basic tools:

```
$ tail -n+$((1 + $(grep -n '^RR$' file.txt | cut -d: -f1))) file.txt
important stuff
$
```

## Using pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
$ { while read ln; do [ "$ln" == RR ] && break; done; cat; } < file.txt 
important stuff
$
```

## And another way, assuming you can guarantee no more than 9999 lines in a file:

```
$ grep -A9999 '^RR$' file.txt | tail -n+2
important stuff
$
```